# Is "gdmflexiserver" part of the default installation?

Tags: 11.10, software-installation, lightdm, gdm, default

While playing around, I discovered a folder in my `$PATH` that I did not recognize:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
$ ls /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm
gdmflexiserver
```

Apparently `gdmflexiserver` is used to start another X session or some such. Is this part of the default package? I don't see the use for it for a normal user, and it seems odd to have in one's path, especially when it is just for one program. Why would it not be under one of the other paths in that case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gdmflexiserver is part of the GDM project and is used to switch displays.  To support applications that are not currently LightDM aware a version is provided that uses the LightDM protocol.  It is placed in a different path to override the GDM version.  It is expected this can be removed in the future.